# google maps API3 opening infowindow in clustered markers from external link

Tags: google-maps, infowindow, markerclusterer

I am trying to open infowindow by clicking to text but when i have clusters i can't call anything Help ??

Image : http://s4.postimg.org/khw51khot/aaa.png

```js
 function open_window(io) { // my function to open info window  from external link
   //alert(io);
   infowindow.setContent(locations[io][0]);
   infowindow.open(map, marker);
   (marker, io);
 }

 function initialize() {

   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


   var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, 110.1419);

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 3,
     center: center,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   });

   var markers = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][1]);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng

     });

     markers.push(marker);
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
       return function() {
         infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
         infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
     })(marker, i));
   }

   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); < /script>
  </head >
 < body >
   < h3 > < /h3>
    <table border="1">
 <tr><td>
    <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div > < /div>
    </td >
   < td width = "400px" >
   < div style = "height:600px;width:400px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:12px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;" >
   < script type = "text/javascript" > // script to generate the links to open window can pass number already tried alert function
   for (io = 0; io < locations.length; io++) {
     document.write(" <p id=" + io + " onclick='open_window(this.id)'>");
     document.write(locations[io][3]);
     document.write(io);
     document.write("</p>");
   } < /script>
  </div >
   < /td>
 </tr >
   < /table>
```

Without cluster i can open infowindow, What i am try to do is that open infowindow and focus map to that maker.

Comment: something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3_clustered.html)?

Comment: i found the way to open info window just took ” var markers[]“ out of initialize function but window  and place and event trigger but info window is not zooming in to maker just opening at middle of map

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved 
1-) place var markers []  out of initialize 
2-) create event trigger function and trigger marker click event
3-) set position to marker position   map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
4-)limit cluster to 9 zoom   maxZoom: 9

infowindow called from a external link and placed in where it is supposed to be :)
and i made it with  3 coffees + 1 coke + 1 snickers chocolate bar.

Comment: It would interesting if you could share the code. 
I'm looking to do more/less the same.

Comment: how does one limit the cluster zoom levels?